# Inconsistent encryption and decryption with OpenSSL RC4 in C++

Tags: c++, linux, encryption, openssl, rc4-cipher

First off, I understand that RC4 is not the safest encryption method and that it is outdated, this is just for a school project. Just thought I put it out there since people may ask.

I am working on using RC4 from OpenSSL to make a simple encryption and decryption program in C++. I noticed that the encryption and decryption is inconsistent. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rc4.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int inputFile = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
if (inputFile < 0) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return 1;
}

unsigned char *keygen = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(argv[2]);
RC4_KEY key;

size_t size = lseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);
lseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

unsigned char *fileIn = (unsigned char*) calloc(size, 1);

if (pread(inputFile, fileIn, size, 0) == -1) {
    perror("Error opening read\n");
    return 1;
}

unsigned char *fileOut = (unsigned char*) calloc(size, 1);

unsigned char *actualKey;
EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_rc4(), EVP_sha256(), NULL, keygen, sizeof(keygen), 1, actualKey, NULL);

RC4_set_key(&key, sizeof(actualKey), actualKey);
RC4(&key, size, fileIn, fileOut);

int outputFile = open(argv[3], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0644);
if (outputFile < 0) {
    perror("Error opening output file");
    return 1;
}
if (pwrite(outputFile, fileOut, size, 0) == -1) {
    perror("error writing file");
    return 1;
}

close(inputFile);
close(outputFile);

free(fileIn);
free(fileOut);

return 0;
}
```

The syntax for running this in Ubuntu is:

```
./myRC4 test.txt pass123 testEnc.txt
```

MOST of the time this works fine, and encrypts and decrypts the file. However occasionally I get a Segmentation fault. If I do, I run the same exact command again and it encrypts or decrypts fine, at least for .txt files.

When I test on .jpg files, or any larger file, the issue seems to be more common and inconsistent. I notice that sometimes the images appear to have been decrypted (no segmentation fault) but in reality it has not, which I test by doing a diff between the original and the decrypted file.

Any ideas as to why I get these inconsistencies? Does it have to do with how I allocate memory for fileOut and fileIn?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `sizeof(actualKey)` is not the size of array pointed at by `actualKey` but the size of the pointer `actualKey`. Are you sure passing this to `RC4_set_key` is correct?

Comment: Same warning for `sizeof(keygen)` and `EVP_BytesToKey`.

Comment: Also the variable `actualKey` looks like used without required initialization. I don't know the API, but is the 7th argument of `EVP_BytesToKey` a reference?

Comment: In general, inconsistencies probably are sign of that you are invoking some *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I see what you mean with sizeof(actualkey) and etc. I believe I am using RC4_set_key correctly, but if you have doubt I can provide the documentation for it: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RC4.html
And EVP_BytesToKey: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html

Sorry if I cannot answer questions the best, extremely mentally exhausted at the moment lol.

Comment: So RC4_set_key needs the length bytes of the key that I pass. If sizeof(actualKey) does not return the length, that would make sense. But I do not understand why/if this would cause inconsistencies with the encrypt/decrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actualKey` needs to be pointing to a buffer of appropriate size before you pass it to `EVP_BytesToKey`.  As it is you are passing in an uninitialised pointer which would explain your inconsistent results.

The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html) for `EVP_BytesToKey` has this to say:

> If `data` is `NULL`, then `EVP_BytesToKey()` returns the number of bytes needed to store the derived key.

So you can call `EVP_BytesToKey` once with the `data` parameter set to `NULL` to determine the length of `actualKey`, then allocate a suitable buffer and call it again with `actualKey` pointing to that buffer.

As others have noted, passing `sizeof(keygen)` to `EVP_BytesToKey` is also incorrect.  You probably meant `strlen (argv [2])`.

Likewise, passing `sizeof(actualKey)` to `RC4_set_key` is also an error.  Instead, you should pass the value returned by `EVP_BytesToKey`.

Comment: This seems to have helped my program! Going to do some more testing to make sure but it is promising so far. Thanks again!